# How can I hover multiple elements in order with using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I want to hover all div under .wrapper div in order with a delay when the page is loaded. How can I do this with using jquery?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.wrapper').children().each(function(){
   $(this).trigger('hover'); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/drxvr1hn/

Comment: You don't have any `hover` event (which anyway isn't an event) to trigger. You are using CSS pseudo class `:hover` in jsFiddle which is untrusted event and cannot be fired using js. Toggle a class instead

Comment: So you want something like that instead: https://jsfiddle.net/drxvr1hn/3/ ???

Answer (score 4):

`.trigger('hover')` has been deprecated as it caused a great deal of maximum stack exceeded errors.

> **Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9:** The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.

Trying to trigger the hover state via jQuery is a very browser/cpu intensive process and a lot of re-rendering of a page to ensure that your call is correct. Therefore the ability was removed but is possible with some JS but will almost certainly cause speed issues and/or stack issues which can cause browser crashes.

A good alternative would be to use classes like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrapper div').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.wrapper div').addClass('hover');
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.wrapper div').removeClass('hover');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.first {
  background-color: #468966;
}
.second {
  background-color: #FFF0A5;
}
.third {
  background-color: #FFB03B;
}
.first.hover {
  background-color: #B64926;
}
.second.hover {
  background-color: #8E2800;
}
.third.hover {
  background-color: #464A66;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the timeOut interval

```
$(window).scroll(function() {      
$('. wrapper'). children().each(function(index){
          var _this = this;
          setTimeout( function(){ $(_this).trigger('hover'); }, 200*index);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't run it. Can you give a working jsfiddle?

Comment: @midstack, you have explanation in first comment.

Comment: @nevermind Well how can I trigger css hover with jquery?